# parse output of a command to only show lines based on range of data from a specific column

Tags: text-processing

This is certainly a case of rtfm, as I've come across many similar posts, but I'm getting lost in trying to find what I'm looking for. I imagine awk or grep will be able to help somehow, I could use some assistance in pointing me in the right direction.

I have a future plan of writing a script with prompts that another user can run for this function, but first I want to get the basic idea to work for myself.

I need to use `who -u` to display currently logged on users, and then based on the time they are idle for, display their userid, idle time, and pid.

For example,

```
01sale1  pts/11       2016-10-05 06:39 00:04       14132 (192.168...)
01sale2  pts/16       2016-10-05 06:40 00:07       17902 (192.168...)
01sale3  pts/14       2016-10-05 06:40   .         17779 (192.168...)
01sale5  pts/25       2016-10-05 06:41 00:04       18339 (192.168...)
```

The list is quite long when everyone is on, and we are running into issues reaching the limit of licenses for this specific software. Until that is resolved, I need to kick users idle over an hour or so.

What I would like is to run who -u to show me just columns 1, 5 and 6 based on if column 6 is over an hour, so it would appear 01:** or above.

Eventually, I want to make a script that a user without root privileges can run to show them this info, and then kill idle users. I'm not sure if I want this totally automated or not yet though.

I'm running this application on an older Red Hat

Comment: In case your users login via ssh. It may be better to log them out if their connection is idle (when they are doing nothing for some time). `/etc/sshd_config`: `ClientAliveInterval 3600` and  `ClientAliveCountMax 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idle time is derived from the last access time of the tty device, so you could do:

```
kill_idle() (
  sig=$1
  old_ttys=$(find /dev/pts -type c ! -name ptmx -amin +60 -printf %p,)
  [ "$#" -eq 0 ] || pkill "-$sig" -t "$old_ttys"
)
kill_idle HUP; sleep 3; kill_idle KILL
```

To kill all the processes controlled by those inactive ttys.

Now, as rightly pointed out by @rudimeter, `/dev/pts` devices are not always only used for user terminal sessions, so we may end-up killing processes that use pseudo-terminals for other purposes (like `expect`, `socat` or pty using other terminal disciplines).

Things like terminal emulators, getty, screen, sshd register the pseudo-terminals that they spawn in the `utmp` database which is what `who -u` queries.

To get the *idle* terminals from the output of `who -u` instead, you could do:

```
old_ttys=$(
  who -u | awk '$5 != "." && $5 !~ /^00/ {printf "%s,", $2}'
)
```

Note however that the output of `who -u` can be tampered with on systems that use `utempter` to register the pty.

For instance, here using `socat` to create the pty:

```
name=$':0)\nnobody pts/2 2016-10-05 00:00 old 123 (:0' socat pty \
  system:'/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/utempter/utempter add \"$name\"; sleep infinity',nofork &
```

`utempter` is a sgid command that adds the entry in utmp. It does validate its input to some extent, as in its stdin has to point to `ptmx` and the corresponding slave pts must be owned by the caller, but it doesn't validate the *host* field. Here by specifying a *host* field with a newline character in it, we're making a fake entry in the output of `who -u`:

```
nobody pts/2 2016-10-05 00:00 old 123 (:0)
```

That means one can make you kill the processes on any pts.

---

To just list the idle terminals:

```
who -u | awk '$5 != "." && $5 !~ /^00/'
```

Or just to list the user, idle time and pid of the controlling process of the terminal:

```
who -u | awk '
  $5 != "." && $5 !~ /^00/ {printf "%-16s %6s %d\n", $1, $5, $6}'
```

The `w` command might give you a more useful output (it's also not vulnerable to the exploit mentioned above):

```
$ w -sf | awk 'NR > 2 && $3 !~ /[0-9]s?$/'
stephane tty7      50days /usr/bin/lxsession -s LXDE -e LXDE
stephane pts/1      3:07m /bin/zsh
stephane pts/3      1:25m elinks
```

Comment: Hm, this finds also pids for ttys which are not shown in `who -u`. And seems that it often kills pids when they don't exist anymore. That's not good in case such particular pid is re-used already.

Comment: @rudimeter, that's a TOCTOU race (albeit a very small one, now further reduced by using pkill instead of ps+kill, see edit). Not much you can do about it. I agree that it's probably better to only look at ptys that register with utmp (show in who -u) as ptys could be used for something else than user terminal sessions.

Comment: I'd like to include this in possible future scripts, but for now, I'd just like to see what is idle before automatically killing it. Thanks though

Comment: That is very informative @StéphaneChazelas, I'll have to check back with this as this proposed script grows. Thanks!

Comment: @MikeD, I did add the listing of idle terminals in a later edit (see the last line). But again, what you see might have been forged.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas perhaps I should consider using this instead, for the reasons you mentioned. I was also hoping to save some typing with the kill command. For the longest time I was using fuser -k /dev/pts/### to do the killing, I only recently started to use kill {PID} because I'm very lazy

Comment: @MikeD, `fuser -k` would kill the processes that have at least one fd open on the tty, while `pkill -t` would kill the processes _controlled_ by the terminal (those in the session attached to the terminal). So `fuser -k` could kill the wrong processes (like `wall` or `write` commands) and could fail to kill processes started in the terminal session that redirect their std(in,out,err) away from the terminal (like `cmd > /dev/null 2>&1 &`). Both would not kill _daemonized_ processes (those that detach from the terminal by closing all their fds and start a new session).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, Oh ok, thanks again! So the proper kill command would look like `pkill -t pts/###`? Further to my laziness, could I make an alias for that like pkill2 or something so I just have to type `pkill2 ###`? I've started using my phone occassionally to kill idle users when I'm out of the office, it would save me a bit of typing

Comment: @MikeD, if you're lazy, I suppose you already use `zsh`, so: `k() pkill -r ${(j:,:):-pts/$^@}` to be used as `k 23 5 26...`

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
who -u | \
awk '$5 ~ /^[0-9][1-9]:.*$|^[1-9][0-9]:.*$/ {printf "%s %s %s\n", $1,$5,$6}'
```

`awk` match for patterns beginning with `0[1-9] || [1-9][0-9]`.
You could try to match patterns *not beginning* with `00` if you want.

Comment: Good lord, that's wonderful! By the way, I can't count... it should have been column 5, so I changed awk to $2 as you originally had it. I've been trying to find something like this for a while now, thank you very much! :)

Comment: You could avoid `tr` and `cut`: `who -u | awk '$5 ~ /^[0-9][1-9]:.*$|^[1-9][0-9]:.*$/ {print $1,$5,$6}'`

Comment: Ok @Mike_D ... I've made a rollback to my answer ;)

Comment: Why would you compact spaces and cut fields exernally, when the next step is Awk??? Don't you realize that the default `FS` in Awk matches  multiple spaces (and trims leading and trailing space) and that you can do `$0="$1 $5 $6"` to reduce the record to just the needed fields (and have it split again into fields).

Comment: @Kaz answer updated

Comment: `printf("%s %s %s\n", x, y, z)` is an anti-pattern in Awk, precisely identical to `print x, y, z` when `OFS` and `RS` have their default values of space and newline, respectively. (By the way, sorry about that! No, you can't do `$0="$1 $5 $6"`).

Comment: Thanks. I always tend to use `printf` instead of `print` just to have more "portable" solutions. I mean: expected output on different configurations (`OFS`, `RS`, as you say). So it is a wrong rule ?